# MVVMCross 3.5.1 and xamarin android does not work

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a question: is there somebody that use  MVVMCross 3.5.1 with Api level android 21 and xamarin studio 5.9.3? I have a problem: I reference mvvmcross in an android app. I have a splashscreen and a firstview. When I tried to start with emulator I don't have any problem with level 15 emulator but when I tried it with the last version (Api 21) the app after splashscreen is closed without any error (not open the firstview).

Is there  a solution?

**UPDATE**

I tried with **logcat**. In the following I attached the log:

```
   W/AudioTrack(  394): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
   I/ActivityManager(  394): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.
   intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.nowhere.nowhere/md51f5aeae0dbe3
   fa3acab67292d41114d1.SplashScreen (has extras)} from uid 10007 on display 0
   I/Choreographer(  824): Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too muc
   h work on its main thread.
   I/art     ( 1716): Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
   I/ActivityManager(  394): Start proc com.nowhere.nowhere for activity com.nowher
   e.nowhere/md51f5aeae0dbe3fa3acab67292d41114d1.SplashScreen: pid=1716 uid=10056 g
   ids={50056, 9997, 3003} abi=armeabi-v7a
   I/Choreographer(  394): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too muc
   h work on its main thread.
   F/MonoDroid( 1716): shared runtime initialization error: dlopen failed: library
   "/data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/arm/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so" not found
   I/Zygote  (   66): Process 1716 exited cleanly (1)
   I/ActivityManager(  394): Process com.nowhere.nowhere (pid 1716) has died
   I/art     ( 1731): Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
   I/ActivityManager(  394): Start proc com.nowhere.nowhere for activity com.nowher
   e.nowhere/md51f5aeae0dbe3fa3acab67292d41114d1.SplashScreen: pid=1731 uid=10056 g
   ids={50056, 9997, 3003} abi=armeabi-v7a
   F/MonoDroid( 1731): shared runtime initialization error: dlopen failed: library
   "/data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/arm/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so" not found
   I/Zygote  (   66): Process 1731 exited cleanly (1)
   I/ActivityManager(  394): Process com.nowhere.nowhere (pid 1731) has died
   I/art     ( 1746): Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
   I/ActivityManager(  394): Start proc com.nowhere.nowhere for activity com.nowher
   e.nowhere/md51f5aeae0dbe3fa3acab67292d41114d1.SplashScreen: pid=1746 uid=10056 g
   ids={50056, 9997, 3003} abi=armeabi-v7a
   F/MonoDroid( 1746): shared runtime initialization error: dlopen failed: library
   "/data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/arm/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so" not found
   I/Zygote  (   66): Process 1746 exited cleanly (1)
   I/ActivityManager(  394): Process com.nowhere.nowhere (pid 1746) has died
   W/ActivityManager(  394): Force removing ActivityRecord{27f513c9 u0 com.nowhere.
   nowhere/md51f5aeae0dbe3fa3acab67292d41114d1.SplashScreen t8}: app died, no saved
    state
   W/WindowManager(  394): Failed looking up window
   W/WindowManager(  394): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window and
   roid.view.ViewRootImpl$W@3c7a1def does not exist
   W/WindowManager(  394):         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.wi
   ndowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8412)
   W/WindowManager(  394):         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.wi
   ndowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8403)
   W/WindowManager(  394):         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.re
   moveWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2558)
   W/WindowManager(  394):         at com.android.server.wm.Session.remove(Session.
   java:186)
   W/WindowManager(  394):         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFro
   mWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:2920)
   W/WindowManager(  394):         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.
   java:5390)
   W/WindowManager(  394):         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.han
   dleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3223)
   W/WindowManager(  394):         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
   va:102)
   W/WindowManager(  394):         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   W/WindowManager(  394):         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.ja
   va:61)
   W/WindowManager(  394):         at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceT
   hread.java:46)
   W/InputMethodManagerService(  394): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain
   of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@14f4aa0b attribute=n
   ull, token = android.os.BinderProxy@5c9e508
   I/Choreographer(  824): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too muc
   h work on its main thread.
   D/TaskPersister(  394): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=8_task.xml
```

**UPDATE 2**
The bind does not work. Inside the view..

**UPDATE 3**
I put the code in this repo:

[https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1E563B1D1AD8A1C!15847&authkey=!AII01sfuzToQiUQ&ithint=file%2czip](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1E563B1D1AD8A1C!15847&authkey=!AII01sfuzToQiUQ&ithint=file%2Czip)

I used this configuration for the test: 
1. Nexus 5, 
2. Android 5.0-API Level 21,
3. CPU/ABI, I have chosen Google APIs Intel Atom(x86_64),
4. Use Host GPU.

**UPDATE 4**
new link for code: http://1drv.ms/1MZWf45

Thanks
Alessandro

Comment: Have you checked logcat?

Comment: Hi, I tried with logcat, this is the result:

Comment: Can you post your code or link to a repo we can reproduce from?  Are you doing fragments right now?

Comment: I put the code example in this repo:

Comment: You example is incomplete. You reference LoginViewModel but there is none. Also you use Xamarin Forms, but you don't need that if i understand your project correctly. As for the Android Target framework: you should manually select 5.0 there instead of use latest. Also the Android v4 library is outdated, and could potentially have fixes for Android 5 in the latest version.

Comment: Thanks, the problem on LoginViewModel was only a bad copy&paste when I preparted the testCode. I updated the solution but I have always the same problem. Inside the link there is the last version.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The problem was the emulator. I tried to change the configuration and now run without problem.

Thanks
Al.